# keys of a hash that loads from a json string

Tags: ruby

We know that Ruby has a feature of symbol, typically a symbol is used as a hash key that save space vs a string object. Say:

```
myhash[:mykey] = "myvalue"
```

But if I load a hash from json string, say:

```
str = '{"mykey": "myvalue"}'
myhash = JSON.parse(str)
```

Then I must use string key to access the hash:

```
puts myhash["mykey"]  # myvalue
```

Is this reasonable? Why JSON.parse just put symbol for hash keys?

Comment: One reason may be because symbols with non-alphanumeric characters will need the quotes anyway, so it would actually get more clumsy. For instance, if a json key were "hi there" then the ruby symbol would be :"hi there". Easier to just be a string in the general case.

Comment: JSON isn't a Ruby-only format, nor was it written for Ruby first. It's a representation of how JavaScript defines objects, which turned out to be very useful for all languages needing to throw data around. Few other languages support symbols, especially JavaScript, so including symbol support wasn't necessary or especially desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning keys as strings is `JSON` default behavior. You can override by providing additional  `symbolize_names` argument.

```
str = '{"mykey": "myvalue"}'
JSON.parse(str)
#=> {"mykey"=>"myvalue"}

JSON.parse(str, {:symbolize_names => true})
#=> {:mykey=>"myvalue"}
```

As @Matt said, in his comment, if the key happens to have whitespace (eg: *my key* ), it will key it as- `:"my key"`.